# Can't run Mathematica on Raspberry Pi under php

Tags: raspberry-pi, licensing

Since *Mathematica* is contained in Raspberry Pi 2, I can do the following in the terminal:

```
echo "2+2" | /usr/local/bin/math -batchinput -batchoutput
```

It outputs `4` correctly. But when I try it with php:

```
<?php
$math="echo '2+2' | /usr/local/bin/math -batchinput -batchoutput";
$handle = popen($math, "r");
$str=fread($handle,200);
echo $str;
?>
```

It says that

> Mathematica cannot find a valid password.

I find the license for *Mathematica*, in

```
/opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/10.0/Configuration/Licensing/mathpass
```

Does this mean that *Mathematica* needs another license for interface with php?

**UPDATE**

I have solved this by adding an active key and password for the user `www-data`, which will stored in `/var/www/.WolframEngine/Licensing/mathpass`.

Comment: Under what user account does the php interpreter run? You may need to add this account to the `video` group.

Comment: @ilian how to check the user for php interpreter?

Comment: I find the problem, when I login with `sudo su www-data` then `math 2+2` ask me to active the product.

Comment: On a standard RPi install, the CLI version of Mathematica is *wolfram* not *math*.

Answer (score 8):

*Mathematica* on the Raspberry Pi already comes with a license preinstalled, however running it as a user with insufficient access privileges may result in a prompt for activation or a password.

Here is a slightly more detailed explanation of what is happening, which is also discussed on [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/444854).

Early in the kernel (or FrontEnd) startup, as part of a series of hardware checks, *Mathematica* needs to talk to the Broadcom VideoCore chip. The default permissions for device should be similar to

```
crw-rw---- 1 root video 250, 0 Oct 27 22:17 /dev/vchiq
```

For example, if the user is not a member of the `video` group, opening the device will fail, resulting in a different `$MachineID` which no longer matches the preinstalled password. Hence, the product will not be activated.

A good way to resolve this issue is to check the device permissions are as above, and add the non-privileged user to the `video` group

```
sudo usermod -a -G video www-data
```

> I have solved this by adding an active key and password for the user `www-data`

Yes, this will also work, but is more expensive: it requires the Pi owner (or his organization) to have purchased a *Mathematica* license. That is not necessary on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: It seems that if I add the user `www-data` to group `video` as you said, then I can execute `math 2+2` for the user `www-data` without invalid passward warning, but to the web php code, it still returns the invalid password warning.

Comment: I missed Mathematica on the Raspberry Pi already comes with a license preinstalled, however running it as a user with insufficient access privileges may result in a prompt for activation or a password. Now everythins is fine,
thank you very much.